# Azure DevOps pipeline continues to run despite removing schedule

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am working on a project using Azure DevOps pipelines, and I'm facing an issue with pipeline runs persisting even after removing the schedule.

I removed the schedule section from my Azure DevOps pipeline YAML file, but the pipeline continues to run on a schedule. I'm not sure what's causing this unexpected behavior.

I have a simplified version of my pipeline YAML file without the schedule section. Here it is:

```yaml
trigger:
    branches:
        include:
            - develop 

pr: none
pool:
    vmImage: ubuntu-20.04
```

Please let me know if you have any idea why the scheduler is still running despite the removal of the schedule section from the YAML file. Your insights would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that there are no schedule triggers in your pipeline settings (created from the DevOps UI, not from YAML)?

Comment: Indeed, no schedule triggers have been set up through the DevOps UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to wipe the slate clean by removing the pipeline, its builds, and all related artifacts, only to rebuild and recreate it once more in Azure DevOps. That solved my problem.